# jquery: sum of all input fields in invoice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create an invoice that calculates the total price by quantity and total of all totals.

The first part is working but the second part is not working.

In my code I have:

```
<?php foreach ($invoiceItems as $index => $invoiceItem) { ?>
    <tr class="create-invoice-tr-body-items">
        <td style="width: 12%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
            <?= $form->field($invoiceItem, '['.$index.']product_code')->textInput(['id'=> 'itemNo_'.$index , 'class' => 'inp-code'])->label(false) ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 45%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
            <?= $form->field($invoiceItem, '['.$index.']product_name')->textInput(['id'=> 'itemName_'.$index , 'class' => 'inp-name'])->label(false) ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 10%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
            <?= $form->field($invoiceItem, '['.$index.']product_price')->textInput(['id'=> 'price_'.$index , 'class' => ''])->label(false) ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 9%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
            <?= $form->field($invoiceItem, '['.$index.']product_unite')->textInput(['id'=> 'unity_'.$index , 'class' => ''])->label(false) ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 9%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
            <?= $form->field($invoiceItem, '['.$index.']product_qtt')->textInput(['id'=> 'quantity_'.$index , 'class' => ''])->label(false) ?>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 15%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
            <?= $form->field($invoiceItem, '['.$index.']product_total')->textInput(['id'=> 'total_'.$index , 'class' => 'inp-prod-total'])->label(false) ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>

    <?= $form->field($invoice, 'invoice_subtotal')->textInput(['id'=>'inv_subtotal'])->label(false) ?>
```

My javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var i;
for (i = 0; i < <?=$index?>; i++) { 
    $("#quantity_"+i).keyup(function(){
        total = $("#quantity_"+i).val()* $("#price_"+i).val();
        $("#total_"+i).val(total);
    });
}

var sum = 0;
$(".inp-prod-total").each(function(){
    if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
        sum += +parseFloat($(this).val());
    }
});
$("#inv_subtotal").val(sum);

</script>
```

The first part that calculates price x quantity is working.

This part is working:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < <?=$index?>; i++) { 
    $("#quantity_"+i).keyup(function(){
        total = $("#quantity_"+i).val()* $("#price_"+i).val();
        $("#total_"+i).val(total);
    });
}
```

But the second part to calculate total of all totals which has `id = inv_subtotal` is not working. Not all inputs can have a value, sometimes I have only two items, sometimes I can have 4 or 6 items, it depends.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is a proof-of-concept. Pls notice it's sums up the fields.

Hope all is more clear now.

```
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>JSfiddle</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="create-invoice-tr-body-items">
      <td style="width: 12%;" class="ly-inv-preview-show-borders-cell">
        <form>
          <input class="inp-name" type="text" value="20" />
          <input class="inp-name" type="text" value="20" />
          <input class="inp-name" type="text" value="20" />
          <input class="inp-name" type="text" value="20" />
          <input class="inp-name" type="text" value="20" />
        </form>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      var sum = 0;
      //perform loop accros all class elems
      $('table tr td .inp-name').each(function (i, obj) {
        //console.log(i, obj);
        // cache varialbe
        let $objVal = $(obj).val();
        if ($objVal !== NaN && typeof $objVal !== "undefined") {
          sum += parseFloat($objVal);
        }
      });
      console.log(sum);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried your code but it's always 0 I did change alert(sum) to $("#inv_subtotal").val(sum); it's not change always 0

Comment: it's not change I add photo to see the zero not change after I add your code

Comment: weird, having the html structure as shown above computes the value properly

Comment: I add photo of inspect element , the code is in my question

Comment: I'm getting NaN in console log

Comment: I think problematic in this case is a way you are updating the .inp-name  elements and submit the form. The code I have provided sums up the fields with values on page load.

Comment: no thing change I'm getting NaN I add some photo to show you class in element and also console log

Comment: what have noticed you haven't put your js code within:  $(document).ready(function(){ ... }). You use jquery so must initialize it first...

Comment: and change class in code $('table tr td .inp-name') into $('table tr td .inp-prod-total')

Comment: I'm using my function inside  $(document).ready(function(){ ... }). also I changed .inp-name to .inp-prod-total but nothing changed :'(

Comment: Are you submitting the form (if so event must be susbscribed)? Or result should be shown on page load (make sure fields have correct values)?

Comment: No I'm not submitting the form

Comment: looks like input fields don't have values on load

Comment: sorry I was late to answer; you are right input fields don't have any values on load

Comment: great - if they have values the above JS code will work correctly

Comment: is it working? if 'yes' can you upvote and mark as solved :)

Comment: sorry I have no internet that why I take time to answer; Still no luck :'(

Comment: have the php values being set correctly? if yes apply to above js code/amend css class if needed